# How to parallel filter data by value's truthy in Clojure?

Tags: dictionary, filter, clojure, reduce, clojurescript

We have some data like this:

```
(def x {:title ["NAME" "CODE" "ORDER" "MIN" "MAX" "IMG"]
        :show-in-list [true true true true false false]
        :key [:name :code :order :min :max :image]
        :input-type [:txt :txt :num :num :num :img]
        :value [nil nil nil nil nil nil]
        :required [true true false false false false]})
```

We want to filter these values by `:required`'s bool value which results in:

```
{:title ["NAME" "CODE"],
 :show-in-list [true true],
 :key [:part_name :part_code],
 :input-type [:txt :txt],
 :value [nil nil],
 :required [true true]}
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried and how it failed so we can improve on it.

Comment: This would result in `{:title ["NAME" "CODE" ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter each element with ':required' vector:

```clj
(let [x {:title        ["NAME" "CODE" "ORDER" "MIN" "MAX" "IMG"]
         :show-in-list [true false true true false false]
         :key          [:name :code :order :min :max :image]
         :input-type   [:txt :txt :num :num :num :img]
         :value        [nil nil nil nil nil nil]
         :required     [true true false false false false]}]
  (->> x
       (map (fn [[k v]]
              ;; value v (which is a vector) is filtered out by its :required filter
              [k  (->> (map #(if %1 %2 ::false) (:required x) v)
                       ;; remove ::false element
                       (remove #(= ::false %)))]))
       ;; add the updated key-value pair
       (into (empty x))))
```

returns...

```
{:title        ("NAME" "CODE"),
 :show-in-list (true false),
 :key          (:name :code),
 :input-type   (:txt :txt),
 :value        (nil nil),
 :required     (true true)}
```

Comment: I know i'm slightly moving the goal posts but this function doesn't quite work as intended. For example if the first value in `:show-in-list` was `false` the value should still show but in this solution would be filtered out by the `remove false?`

Comment: I missed the "false" case - added now with namespaced keyword to do filter

Answer (score 1):

i would advice slightly different approach: 
since you already need to filter out data in this 'packed' data structure, i guess you would potentially need to perform some other operations on it, so won't it be better to unpack/decompose the data structure to separate maps?

it could look like this:

```
(defn decompose [data]
  (let [ks (keys data)]
    (apply map #(zipmap ks %&) (vals data))))
```

this one unpacks the data:

```
user> (decompose x)


({:title "NAME",
  :show-in-list true,
  :key :name,
  :input-type :txt,
  :value nil,
  :required true}
 {:title "CODE",
  :show-in-list true,
  :key :code,
  :input-type :txt,
  :value nil,
  :required true}
  ;;....more maps
)
```

then the `recompose`:

```
(defn recompose [data]
  (when (seq data)
    (apply merge-with
           conj
           (zipmap (keys (first data)) (repeat []))
           data)))
```

this one, in turn, packs back the unpacked data.

so now your task could be fulfilled by simply filtering decomposed data and recomposing it back:

```
(->> x
     decompose
     (filter :required)
     recompose)

;;=> {:title ["NAME" "CODE"],
;;    :show-in-list [true true],
;;    :key [:name :code],
;;    :input-type [:txt :txt],
;;    :value [nil nil],
;;    :required [true true]}
```

To me it looks more general, and (what is more important) more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn bar [state [required value]]
  (if required (conj state value) state))

(defn foo [required values]
  (reduce bar [] (map vector required values)))

(zipmap (keys x) (map #(foo (:required x) %) (vals x)))
```

> We want to filter these values by :required's bool value

Pair required and value, if required then add value to new collection

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: @EduardoBaitello Thank you for pointing that out. I will update my comment now.